# Fixed elements (HTML) break after android keyboard dissapears?

Tags: android, html, css, position, trigger.io

I am trying to place a text input at the bottom of the viewport/screen.  It works fine, it even "sticks" to the top of the keyboard after the onfocus event.

When the keyboard is closed, however, there is lag between the changed position (top of keyboard) and the original position (bottom of viewport).

My css for the element is :

```
.fixed {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1000;
    height: 50px;
    display: block;
    bottom: 0px;
    width: 100%;
 }
```

**EDIT:**

This behavior doesn't depend on fixed/absolute positioning only.  Also inputs with position:relative or position:static have the same issue.  It seems like the softkeyboard disappears much faster than the screen/browser view can update itself.  Seems like a memory issue or a deep bug within Android's default browser (kill me now).

Here are some screenshots.

On focus :

http://i.cubeupload.com/AQS7h8.png

On blur (note the blue screen ± is that a mem issue?):

http://i.cubeupload.com/nV3kMh.png

Comment: Dont use "position: absolute". In that way, the keyboard appears under your element any time. Else, no way without dynamic editing your view-port height while Keyboard is seen... but that will not work good because of different device heights due to android devices. Btw. the native Android view will work as same.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @lin.  I am using position:absolute and the keyboard still appears under my element.  When I use relative or static the keyboard goes above the element, which is undesired. Does it have to do with the android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
setting?

Comment: So if I understood you correctly, the keyboard is blurred (which takes some time) and your element is moved back to the bottom only after the keyboard is completely gone? Maybe as a workaround you could hide your input field instantly when the onblur event is fired and show it again after the document resize happed (or after a few ms).

Comment: @PatrickRudolph Yes that is exactly what happens.  However, I have tried hiding the input element before and after the blur event, even with a settimeout.  I should try with the document resize event but I don't think that's the problem. It seems like softkeyboard is faster than the browser's resize. I will add some photos.

Comment: I'm also seeing that delay in my Android webview apps. It looks like the effect increases on weaker devices.
Another question on the same issue was posted last year. Maybe this is of any help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16188539/trigger-io-android-webview-app-grey-background-appearing-after-keyboard-closes

Comment: Thanks.  I realized that it depends on the device.  Thanks @PatrickRudolph

Answer (score 0):

Had the similar case with android keyboard ruining layout, the following code should work for you.

We are getting current position from top, setting the top style value, and resetting bottom value.

```
var fixed = document.querySelector(".fixed"),
    distanceFromTop = fixed.getBoundingClientRect().top;
fixed.style.top = distanceFromTop + 'px';
fixed.style.bottom = 'auto';
```